# Лицар і рицар - синоніми, семантично різні поняття чи, можливо, "рицар" - це суржик?

Tags: синоніми, суржик

[Словник української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47647&page=1502) містить інформацію, що:

**ЛИ́ЦАР**, я, ч.1. іст. Середньовічний дворянський титул в Європі, а також людина, що мала цей титул; **рицар**.

Отже, тут вважається, що це *"близькі" синоніми або "практично" ідентичні слова.*

На сайті [Dictionaries24.com](https://www.dictionaries24.com/uk/%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%80) пише, що *"лицар"* і *"рицар"* - це і *споріднені слова, і синоніми*.

Цікаво і те, що знайшла інформацію на [Офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/antisurzhik_pravilna_mova/5-1-0-244), де пише, що *правильно* лише *"лицар"*, адже лексема *"рицар"* вважається *суржиком*.

Отже, як насправді є?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По-перше, зазначу, що так званий [«Офіційний сайт Української мови»](//ukrainskamova.com) **не є офіційним сайтом** української мови. Я не знаю, чи може взагалі якась мова мати офіційний сайт (для мене це звучить як «офіційний сайт весни» чи «офіційний сайт землетрусу», адже мова — це перш за все хаотичне суспільне явище), але якщо хтось і може представляти українську мову — то це мовознавчі інститути під керівництвом Національної академії наук України (що згідно з частиною 4 статті 6 Закону України «Про засади державної мовної політики» від 03.07.2012 № 5029-VI мають право встановлювати норми української мови через правопис і словники), але ані так званий «Офіційний сайт…», ані НАНУ не декларують нічого про стосунок одного до одного.

Хоча часто так званий «Офіційний сайт Української мови» публікує доволі корисну інформацію, але в даному випадку — це просто передрук чергового «переліку суржиків» (причому без зазначення авторів чи джерела). Зазвичай такі списки (навіть при зазначенні редакційної колегії) неточні і містять слова, що хибно позначені як суржик; і кожне слово треба перевіряти окремо за надійними джерелами. Хоча такі списки певною мірою корисні, адже вони сприяють збереженню українською мовою своєї ідентичністі (невитісненню локальних слів словами з ширшим ареалом), але зовсім не все, що вони відмічають як суржик — насправді суржик.

«[Лицар](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47647&page=1502)» і «[рицар](http://sum.in.ua/s/rycar)» — це перш за все два варіанти одного й того самого слова. Аналогічно до «[ведмідь](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7215&page=265)» і «[медвідь](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50352&page=1591)» або «[капосний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=40478&page=1278)» і «[пакосний/пакісний](http://sum.in.ua/s/pakosnyj)». Хоча українці частіше кажуть «ведмідь», «капосний» і «лицар» («медвідь» узагалі діалектне), не треба вважати росіянізмами інші варіанти лише тому, що «у росіян схоже». Річ у тім, що початковими варіантами є саме «пакость» (праслов. «*раkоstь»), «медвідь» (праслов. «*medvědь») і «рицар» (нім. «Ritter») — тож не варто закидати у провину носіям певних діалектів те, що вони фактично зберегли оригінальну вимову точніше, ніж більшість українців. Причому, якщо щодо інших слів ситуація може бути доволі неоднозначною (якесь слово, хай воно і ближче до оригіналу, може бути майже цілком витіснене новим зміненим варіантом), то «рицар» — цілком уживана форма і має безліч траплянь у літературі.

Також я не виключаю, що значення слів «лицар» і «рицар» скоро розійдуться. У мене особисто «лицар» більше асоціюється з благородством, а «рицар» — із середньовічними вершниками. І спочатку я був думав, що це суто моя власна асоціація, але раптом побачив у новому «Словнику української мови» незначну зміну дефініцій, що може натякати саме на розходження значень: для «лицар» [словник 2010-х](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47647&page=1502) містить всі ті самі означення, що й [словник 1970-х років](http://sum.in.ua/f/lycar), але з невеличним доповненням до першого означення: «1. іст. Середньовічний дворянський титул в Європі, а також людина, що мала цей титул**; рицар**» — оцього «[крапка з комою] рицар» не було в словнику 1970-х, і додане воно лише до першого означення, тож можливо, що словник 2010-х прирівнюватиме слово «рицар» уже не до всіх значень слова «лицар» (як це робив словник 1970-х), а лише до першого. Але, допоки не вийшли томи словника 2010-х на літеру «Р» (із, власне, статею для «рицар»), про це ще зарано казати.

Answer (score 3):

Навіть у самих мовознавців немає якоїсь одної думки. Бо, наприклад, в «[Як ми говоримо](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/rycar-lycar)» Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича пише:

> ... краще скрізь, у всіх випадках, користуватись тільки давнім
>   українським словом **лицар**, що прийшло в нашу літературу з уст
>   народу.

А у книжці "[Чи правильно ми говоримо?](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t2199.html)" (мовознавець Євгенія Чак) (інформація взята із форуму Словник.ua) пише:

> Аналіз великої кількості спостережень переконує в тому, що останнім
>   часом переважає тенденція називати рицарем представника
>   військово-землевласницького стану в Західній Європі часів феодалізму,
>   а в інших випадках — вживати слово лицар.

І ця ж Євгенія Чак пише:

> Однак процес вироблення стилістичної норми у вживанні цих слів ще не
>   закінчився.

Гадаю, що поки-що можна вживати як одне, так і інше слово, бо обидва вони є в СУМі.